# Tkinter best button text flipping method

Tags: python-3.x, button, text, tkinter

So I'm working on a tkinter project and one issue I come across is finding a way to flip/rotate a button object's text vertically. One way I can kinda cheat into making this happen is putting a canvas object on top of the button with the canvas being drawn last (as shown below) but is there a cleaner way to approach this by just manipulating the Button object attributes?

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
windowDimensions = (1300,600)
root.title("Mapper")


root.geometry(str(windowDimensions[0])+"x"+str(windowDimensions[1]))

button1=Button(root,text='',width=2,height=9)
button1.place(x=0,y=20)
can = Canvas(root,width=15,height=80)
can.place(x=2,y=30)
can.create_text(0, 80, anchor="nw", angle=90,text='hello',font=("Purisa", 12))

root.mainloop()
```

Edit: A problem I get with doing it this way is any place where the canvas is on the button, it obstructs the ability to click where the canvas is.

Comment: You want the letters on top of each other, or the word turned sideways?

Comment: I want the text on the button turned 90 degrees so that I don't need a canvas ontop of the button object

Comment: Assuming that's a possibility...

Comment: Text cannot be rotated; You'll have to hack your way into this: @Novel answer is one approach; another is to create aa rotated image with PIL, and display it on the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option (which isn't a great option) is to screenshot the button, rotate it in an image editor, and then use that image in your button instead of text.

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()

# .gif file encoded as base64
vert_button_data = '''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=
'''

windowDimensions = (1300,600)
root.title("Mapper")
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(*windowDimensions))
button1_image = PhotoImage(data=vert_button_data)
button1=Button(root,image=button1_image)
button1.place(x=0,y=20)
root.mainloop()
```

You'll lose the hover animation but again that's something you can recreate with images.

To get the base64 encoded data from a .gif you can use this:

```
import codecs
with open('export.gif', 'rb') as f:
    print(codecs.encode(f.read(), 'base64').decode())
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess this is the clunky approach I'm gonna have to use.